# Renaming multiple filex with regex using bash script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, filenames

I need to rename multiple files removing a `refdate` and a `.dta` of the name. The refdate varies from day to day, being in the format `'yyyymmdd'`. Example of file names:

alerts_stock_out_level_2_20210415.dta.csv          ->  alerts_stock_out_level_2.csv
base_simulated_20210721.level2.dta.csv             ->  base_simulated.level2.csv
relation_product-deposit_no_cover_20210531.dta.csv ->  relation_product-deposit_no_cover.csv

Is there any way to do this with regex in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for regular expressions, just [`bash` glob patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) and [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) will do fine:

```
shopt -s extglob # Make sure extended patterns are enabled
for file in *csv; do
    # First remove the .dat
    newname=${file/.dat}
    # And rename the file after removing the _refdate part
    mv "$file" "${newname/_+([0-9])}"
done
```